# How make auto-change in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for Chrome extension that helps me to change shortcuts to full text.

For example I define "thanks_feedback" and after space this extension change it to "Thank you for you feedback."

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search returned this app as the top result: [iMacros for Chrome](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Chrome)